# I cannot use useSelector() on React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following code which I want to return the state to be used for private routes on React Router (allowing the access when `isAuthenticated()` returns true).

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const isAuthenticated = () => {

    const auth = useSelector(state => state)

    return auth
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Line 6:  React Hook "useSelector" is called in function "isAuthenticated" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function
```

I don't know how to fix it. Does anyone know? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Change your function name to  be `useIsAuthenticated` since you're creating a new custom hook.
[custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hooks are only allowed to be used in the definition of other hooks (which have to start with "use") or in the implementation of functional react components. So either directly use it in a component

```
const component = () => {
  const auth = useSelector(state => state)
  return <div> {doSomethingWith(auth)} </div>;
}
```

or, if you intent to use your method isAuthenticated as a new hook, name it as Damian suggested

```
const useIsAuthenticated = () => {
  const auth = useSelector(state => state)
  return auth
}
```